# Why LevelDB and RocksDB need a `masked CRC32`

Tags: crc, crc32, leveldb, rocksdb

From the `crc32.h` of leveldb or rocksdb, we can find a comment saying:

```
static const uint32_t kMaskDelta = 0xa282ead8ul;

// Return a masked representation of crc.
//
// Motivation: it is problematic to compute the CRC of a string that
// contains embedded CRCs.  Therefore we recommend that CRCs stored
// somewhere (e.g., in files) should be masked before being stored.
inline uint32_t Mask(uint32_t crc) {
  // Rotate right by 15 bits and add a constant.
  return ((crc >> 15) | (crc << 17)) + kMaskDelta;
}
```

So, what does it mean? Why we need a mask?

Answer (score 1):

"it is problematic to compute the CRC of a string that contains embedded CRCs."

Try some crc calculator online like this: https://crccalc.com/
Calculate the crc32/sata of some random hexs and append the result to origin hexs , calculate again and you'll find you get 0x00.

That would be problematic if the filesystem or network has its own CRC mechanism as you don't get extra validation-if both origin data and crc in leveldb corrupt and happens to pass the validation, without the mask filesystem's crc can't help you(it still sees a crc of 0x00).

Answer (score 0):

> mask

The "mask" is explained in the comments and the one line of code. It modifies a 32 bit CRC by rotating it right 15 bits and adding a constant.

> Why we need a mask?

The mask isn't "needed", but recommended to make the CRC a bit more complicated than a standard CRC, when storing the CRCs. I don't know why it is recommended to "protect" stored CRCs in this manner. If the "masking" process is fixed and known, then I don't see how it helps with "protecting" stored CRCs. I assume the mask is custom and unknown to others for actual usage.

> it is problematic to compute the CRC of a string that contains embedded CRCs

It's not clear to me what the comment is getting at. It's not that difficult to generate data that can go anywhere in a string so that the calculated CRC is valid. Typically a CRC is appended to a message, but it can be cycled backwards n bits by multiplying the CRC by (1/(2^(n))) (in the proper Galois field), with a carryless multiply, which can be sped up using an instruction such as X86's pclmulqdq (it uses xmm registers). For example, say a 32 bit CRC is to be stored at bit index *j* of a string with *m* bits, including both data and the CRC. The 32 bits at index *j* are zeroed, then a standard CRC is used to compute the CRC as if it was going to be appended at bit index *m*. Then the CRC is cycled backwards *m* - *j* bits and stored at bit index *j*.

Having multiple CRCs embedded in a string will make it difficult to reverse engineer, but I've seen cases where savefiles used for games had two CRCs, both embedded, and hackers were able to reverse engineer the twin CRC method.

Comment: I have no idea what the quoted comment means but my initial reading was that they're referring to some sort of large data field that is a composite of other fields each of which (or several of which) have _their own CRC_.  So typically I think when you compute the CRC of such a thing each of the embedded fields, with their own CRC, will "0" out, if you know what I'm saying.  So maybe the belief is that the composite field will have less error detection overall.  Though I'm not sure why.